# SQL/Ruby On Rails Project

Tags: android, sql, ruby-on-rails

For a school project, we are to create an android application that incorporates a server some sensors and uses a data source, so I have decided to make a Geo-caching clone, but for my local university.

The university suggests using Axis2 but I have decided to use Ruby on Rails for the server part. I have never learnt Ruby on Rails so I have been reading tutorials and guides online, so I am still a newbie!

Currently I have a User Model setup, with an association with Items. The user Model has a fields of name and email. While the items have a location, name and a keyword.

What I want the server to be able to do, is when a user creates a new item and uploads its coordinates, a keyword is randomly generated, and returned back to the user, is there anyway this can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a keyword you could use a `before_create` callback in your `Item` model:

```
class Item < ActiveRcord::Base
  before_create :generate_keyword

  private

  def generate_keyword
    random_string = SecureRandom.hex(13)
    # returns a random string like => "ec8688e16cbbb4cf4b857f865f"
    self.keyword = random_string
  end
end
```

How this works:

`before_create` is automatically run before a new `Item` object is created, other methods include `after_create`, `before_save`, `after_save` etc. The `save` callbacks are run every time an object is saved, so not just when it's created but also when it's updated.

So I've named the `before_create` method `generate_keyword`. It will then look for a method by that name and run it. The first line creates a random string, and the second line assigns it to the new `Item` object's `keyword` attribute. You need to make sure your `items` table has a `keywork` column for this to work.

`keyword` is assigned just before the object is created (saved for the first time), so there's no need for you to save the object at the end of the method.

Comment: Then how would you put it in the keyword into the item model? Does the generate_keyword automatically return it to the model? I am wanting to create a hash word type thing :)